# Object rest/spread only excising properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I was wondering if it with rest/spread is possible to only override the existing properties on an object:

```
let xy = {
 x: 1,
 y: 2,
} 

let xyz = {
 x: 41,
 y: 23,
 z: 1
}
```

Now i have two objects and i wish to override the existing properties on `xy` without getting the `z` property from `xyz` as well, so my output is the following:

```
xy = {
 x: 41,
 y: 23,
}
```

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just enumerate the properties of `xy` and check in `xyz`.

Comment: Why the value of `x` key is `42`?

Comment: I have updated, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Rest/spread will always stuff into a destination what it finds in a source object, if you don't want to use a loop / want a functional approach, go for [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), e.g.

```
const xyNew = Object.keys(xyz).reduce((res, key) =>
    // if the key is contained in the accumulator, rewrite it with xyz value, else just return the accumulator (res ~ "result")
    res[key] ? { ...res, [key]: xyz[key] } : res
, xy);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple implementation :-)

```
 let xy = {
 x: 1,
 y: 2,
} 

let xyz = {
 x: 41,
 y: 23,
 z: 1
} 
function compute(){
    let key = Object.keys(xy);
    for(let i=0;i<key.length;i++){
        if(key[i] in xyz) xy[key[i]] = xyz[key[i]];
    }
}
compute();
console.log(xy);
```